# Connecting web parts works in Designer, but not by editing on page

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-designer, connected-web-parts

I have created some DataFormWebParts that use a web service data source in SharePoint Designer.  I then exported each one to the site web part gallery.  Each data source is configured with a parameter than can be set by a web part connection.

I then create a web part page in my browser and add in each web part.  They all display data correctly from the underlying web service call. However, creating the connections between them have no effect.  However, if I then edit this page in SharePoint Designer and add connections, they all work perfectly.

I have tried exporting these web parts from SPD both with and without connections already being created (i.e. when there are no connections, each item has no hyperlink).  I am attempting all this in SharePoint 2010.

So can this be made to work in browser edit mode, or have I discovered another SharePoint bug?